# How can I run a Jquery function bound to another selector?

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of Jquery code that does a whole bunch of validation on a field. I currently have this fired on `.blur()`.

As this field can be pre-populated on load by the server, I want to run that validation at that point also, but I don't know how to call the `.blur()` function which is bound to the control.

Here is my code, most of it cut-out for brevity...

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
            $('#txtCityLoader.loader').show();

            if ($('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').val().length == 0) {
                //chuck some errors
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "~/AtomicService/Validation.asmx/DoesCityExist",
                data: "{'country':'" + $('#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#txtCityLoader.loader').hide();
                    if (msg["d"].length > 0) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                        if (data.Response == 'True') {
                            //all is well, tick the box
                        } else {
                            //stuff and nonsense
                        }
                    } else {
                        //do some other stuff
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            });
        });
```

When the page loads and `document.ready()` fires, I'd like to run this function - how do I do that?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate () {             
    $('#txtCityLoader.loader').show();              
    if ($('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').val().length == 0) {
             //chuck some errors             
    }              

    $.ajax({ ... });
}

$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').blur(validate);
$(document).ready(validate);
```

Comment: you should not invoke the method when you bind it (*in both blur and ready method*) .. it should be `.blur(validate)` and `.ready(validate)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to trigger the event that you bound your method to

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').blur()
```

or

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the code in your blur function to a seperate method. eg:

```
//Call your function when the document is ready
$(document).ready(yourFunction);

//Call your function on text box blur
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').blur(yourfunction);

//Your function
function yourFunction()
{
     //Add your existing blur method code and ajax call here
}
```